# Is the inbox link URL correct?

Tags: support

I use to check my stackoverflow.com' inbox by clicking directly on the inbox icon on the top right side of the page. But now, when I click it takes me to: https://stackexchange.com/users/1749757?tab=inbox, which in turn is asking me to create a new account, which I believe I already had:
Checking my Google SSO apps permissions, I see that stackexchange.com has permission to my basic info, specifically stackauth.com

Did my account got deleted?
Do I need to take any extra actions to fix this?

**Update**:

1. After waiting a while after login: click on the icon again.

   1.1. **Update**: In the inbox items popup, click on link "all items"
2. Get to this page:
   https://stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fusers%2f1749757%3ftab%3dinbox
3. Click on login with google icon, and at google's page click on the associated account
4. Then back to https://stackexchange.com/users/oauth/google?code=code I get this:

[image]

5. Click on the link "you're in the wrong place" (I already have an account, right?)
6. It shows me this message:

> You're not logged into Stack Exchange right now. If you have a Stack
>   Exchange account, and you'd like to associate another OpenID with it,
>   here's what to do:
>
> ```
> [Log in](link to https://stackexchange.com/users/login) in to Stack Exchange with your existing OpenID credentials
> Click on your name to go to your user page
> Click the add OpenID link on your user page
> ```

7. Click on "Log in", and back to step 2.

Comment: Certainly weird. Your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1749757/felix) is intact (I can visit that page, it's linked to your SO account), so your account certainly didn't get deleted.

Comment: I also get redirected if I click there when the page hasn't finished loading. Since you get taken to a different site (Stack Exchange, not Stack Overflow), you might get asked to link your Stack Exchange account, which may involve logging in again (the sites are somewhat distinct but use the same login).

Comment: It happens when you click too soon, before the embedded Javascript had a chance to finish its job.  Not a typical problem when you live in New York, Australians need to be more patient.  Ensure you did not disable JS.

Comment: Because it's totally reasonable to have to wait for a full page load just so the script for something in the *top bar* (i.e. the first 5-10% of the page content) will load.

Comment: Should it even *mention* OpenID? Because [Support for OpenID ended on July 25, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018).

Comment: Hans Passant,  BoltClock, Thanks for the suggestion of waiting, but my SO session stays logged in for days. I'm not logging in and click on that icon right away.

Comment: I think you misunderstood us. We're talking about the fact that clicking on the inbox icon too quickly before the page has finished loading takes you to the Stack Exchange page instead of opening the popup like it normally would. Hans is saying you should wait a little longer, and I'm being sarcastic in order to make the point that waiting for a full page load just so that feature works properly is unreasonable.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock, I you are right misunderstood, and now I realized I need to update the steps. When you click on the icon a popup shows up with the list of inbox items, with a link 'all items', which takes me to the "wrong" place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two levels of having a "stackexchange.com profile". The first level is just a network hub of sorts. If you've never logged in on stackexchange.com before, you don't have a profile there and it's just displaying the aggregated information collected from across the network. This is where you are at - you're only seeing a network summary but you do not yet have a profile on the site.

The first time you try to login to stackexchange.com, it *will* ask you to confirm and create a new profile like any other site. **You need to click that button.** Once you've done so, your profile there will officially "exist" - you won't see anything really change other than a drop-down that allows you to select which site you want to copy from and some additional private options only visible to you. It doesn't create a new network account; it will be connected to your existing network account like any other profile you create.

Comment: I finally did this suggestion and all my stack<...> accounts are visible from stackexchange, and the all items link works as expected. Although, I'm still not sure what happened, whether the link issue is a new feature or not.